# Scikit: Is there a way to get back all the untrained items (the test set) from the best estimator when using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

In this simplified example, I am training a Logistic Regression with GridSearchCV.  As always, I want the model to generalize well, so I want to look closely at the *test set* results.  I can't find an easy way to do this when using GridSearchCV.

```
lr_pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', LogisticRegression())])
lr_parameters = {'clf__fit_intercept':[True,False]}

lr_gs = GridSearchCV(lr_pipeline, lr_parameters)
lr_gs = lr_gs.fit(X,y)
lr_gs.best_estimator_.test_set # would like to be able to do something like this
```

I want to further analyze the examples that the model did NOT train on (eg. view their confusion matrix), but since the cross-validation happened transparently, I can't select those examples.  I could do a new train-test-split and retrain but  that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that when you instantiate a `GridSearchCV` object, it has a default parameter called `refit=True`. According to the docs (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV), this parameter means that the model is automatically re-trained on your entire dataset (`X`, as you have defined it here). So by definition, the model trains on all the data, and there is no held-out test data.

If you want held-out test data but still want to use `GridSearchCV`, what you can do is first create a train-test split (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split) and then call `GridSearchCV` on the train portion of your split. Then, you can compare the test results across different kinds of searches (like RandomSearchCV, etc.) or different kinds of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to interpret your wording. But I suspect what you want is to inspect, for the best *parameters*, the predictions of each model fitted on some portion of training data under cross-validation on the corresponding test portions.

Whether good or bad, the `GridSearchCV` implementation discards the fitted models, as well as the tests results used to score it (although you can wrap your estimator in a class that does so if you really want to).

However, there is a utility to get test-set predictions for all held-out test sets under cross-validation: [`cross_val_predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_predict.html). Again, if there's no memoization, this will wastefully re-train the models. Note also that this will return a prediction for *every* instance in `X` under the assumption that cross-validation's test sets were a partition of `X`.

You can simply use `cross_val_predict(lr_gs.best_estimator_, X, y, cv=lr_gs.cv, n_jobs=lr_gs.n_jobs)`